# Python: Funcion de este operador &

Tags: python

queria saber cual es la utilidad de este operador & en el codigo que pondre a continuacion ya que intentando hacer un programa vi en internet que me servia para lo que queria (Que imprima una vez sola la tecla pulsada) pero nose como funciona exctamente, el codigo:

```
import win32api as win
while True:         
    for i in range(0x30,0x5B):                          
        if win.GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 1 != 0:
            print("%c" % i)
```

Si de ese codigo quitamos el operador y el 1, imprime la tecla pulsada demasiadas veces.

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El operador `&` en Python es equivalente al mismo operador en C y otros lenguajes. Hace una operación lógica "and" entre los bits de dos datos numéricos. Esta operación da como resultado, un bit de valor 1 si ambos bits de entrada son 1, y 0 si uno de los dos es 0, y esta operación se realiza *bit a bit* entre todos los bits del operando de la izquierda con los correspondientes bits del operando de la derecha.

En tu caso estás haciendo `&` entre el número retornado por `win.GetAsyncKeyState(i)` y el `1`. Ya que el operando de la derecha es 1, que en binario es `0000...0001`, no importa qué valor tengan los bits del operando de la izquierda, al hacer "and" con la parte que tiene ceros, saldrán ceros en el resultado. Sólo puede afectar al resultado el último bit.

Por tanto, en el fondo lo que se está mirando con este operador es si el último bit de `win.GetAsyncKeyState()` es 1 (en cuyo caso el resultado del `&` será `0000..0001`) o si es cero (en cuyo caso el resultado del `&` será `0000...0000`).

En definitiva, la condición:

```
        if win.GetAsyncKeyState(i) & 1 != 0:
```

Puede leerse como:

> Si el bit más a la derecha de `win.GetAsyncKeyState(i)` es 1 ...

Por otro lado, según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) de la llamada al sistema (Windows) `GetAsyncKeyState()`, el bit más a la derecha (*least significant bit*) será 1 si la tecla fue pulsada después de la anterior llamada a `GetAsyncKeyState()`. La documentación advierte también de que no debes confiar en este comportamiento, pues puede ocurrir que otra aplicación haya llamado antes a esa función (en vez de tu programa), y sea aquella la que reciba ese bit a 1, en vez de tu programa.

### Explicación adicional

`GetAsyncKeyState()` retorna dos bits: el más significativo y el menos significativo, de un dato de 16 bits. El más significativo indica si la tecla está pulsada o no (1, está pulsada, 0 no lo está). El menos significativo indica si la tecla pulsada ya había sido leida antes (1, no había sido leída antes, 0 sí había sido leída).

Por tanto la respuesta de esta función puede ser 0x8001 si la tecla está pulsada y es la primera vez que la leemos, o bien 0x8000 si está pulsada pero ya la habíamos leído, o bien 0x0000 si no está pulsada.

El programa está en un bucle infinito, debido al `while True`. Cada vez que este bucle se repite, se comprueba si un cierto conjunto de teclas (con códigos entre 0x30 y 0x5A) están pulsadas.

Si la comprobación se hiciera sólo con `if win.GetAsyncKeyState(i)`, este `if` sería cierto tanto si se retornó 0x8001 como si se retornó 0x8000. Es decir, es cierto **mientras esté pulsada**. Ya que esta comprobación se efectúa cíclicamente en el bucle `while True`, es posible que el bucle se repita muchas veces mientras la tecla está pulsada, lo que causaría que el `print()` se repitiera muchas veces para esa tecla.

Al hacer el `& 1`, se está comprobando explícitamente si el bit menos significativo es 1. Entonces será cierto para la respuesta 0x8001, pero falso para la respuesta 0x8000. De este modo sólo haces el print cuando detectas la pulsación, pero no en posteriores iteraciones si la tecla sigue pulsada.

Si la tecla se deja de pulsar, la función retornará 0x0000, lo que también resulta en "falso" al hacerle `& 1`, por lo que no se imprime nada. Si se vuelve a pulsar la tecla, la función retornará 0x8001, con lo que el `&1` daría "true" otra vez y se imprimiría de nuevo. En definitiva, ese truco te permite imprimir el mensaje cada vez que es pulsada, pero no mientras siga pulsada dentro de la misma pulsación.

Fíjate no obstante que, según para qué lo necesites, puede interesarte saber si la tecla está pulsada o no, en lugar de saber si ha sido pulsada o no. Por ejemplo en videojuegos en los que el personaje se mueve *mientras* la tecla está pulsada, y deja de moverse cuando deja pulsarse. En estos casos no te interesa mirar el estado del bit menos significativo.

Comment: Y porque al quitar el & se imprimen un monton de pulsaciones y con el operador en la linea no?

Comment: @Franco He ampliado la respuesta para explicar este comportamiento

Comment: Entonces el ultimo bit es 1 en el momento en el que presiono la tecla , despues pasa a ser 0 , pero si mantengo puslado el boton pasa a ser 1 cada cierto tiempo?

Comment: @Franco He reescrito la explicación final para que quede más claro. Como ves, el bit bajo sólo vuelve a 1 cada vez que se vuelva a pulsar la tecla.